# Is there any countable noun which is a synonym of 'rating'?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

What noun can be used to describe how many times something has been rated?

For voting, you can say "one vote" or "two votes".

For liking (Facebook), you can say "one like" or "two likes".

For rating, I don't think someone would say "one rate" or "two rates".

What's the right word in this case?

Comment: Can you post an example sentence where you might use it? It would be better. :)

Comment: I think it would rating for the singular and ratings for the plural.  You have 1 rating or you have 2 ratings.  You could also say you have been rated x time(s).

Comment: @Alenanno here: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10236/using-color-range-to-make-votes-and-replies-stand-out-without-confusing-the-user the word will replace 'votes' since it implies that something has to be selected.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are referring to the number of times it has been rated, the countable noun would be ratings.

> This post has received 5 positive ratings and 2 negative ratings.

Answer (score 5):

One would usually say:

> A rating of two, a rating of one

E.g.

"The washing machine had a rating of five stars."

Comment: well, right now I'm building a website where you can give thumbs up and thumbs down (like English SE). But there isn't right answers nor sorting. I'm not sure how to call it.

Comment: You could possibly go, "This answer has been given a rating of two thumb ups by users"

Comment: haha is too long, it should be just one word.

Comment: the word will replace the votes: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10236/using-color-range-to-make-votes-and-replies-stand-out-without-confusing-the-user (see the vote part) Because someone told me that votes implies that something has to be selected.

Answer (score 2):

*Rating* is already countable. You can tell because when you use it in a sentence, say:

> He received a rating of 93%.

You can use the word 'a' before rating. Non-countable words don't have this; you never put 'a' or 'an' before a non-countable word. 'a' and 'an' are counting words; they indicate one.

Since you do use 'a' for rating, it is already countable, and you just use the plural form of the word. You can usually check a dictionary to find the plural form of a word. In many cases, you just add 's' or 'es' to the end of a word, but this isn't always true. It is in this case, though.

These are both correct:

> He received a rating of 93%.
>   He received two ratings, one of 92% and one of 95%.

You might list this on a website like this...

```
 Ratings:
   55  X
   12  XX
   10  XXX
    4  XXXX
    5  XXXXX
```

To indicate 55 1-star ratings, 12 2-star ratings, etc.

Oh, and sorry if I got way too basic. I'm not meaning to insult your intelligence or anything, I just like to be really thorough.

Comment: my rating system don't use percentage. It is just like, for example, 1 vote, -1 vote or 2 votes.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with ***grades*** and its synonyms: *marks*, *scores*<sup>[1]</sup>, ***appraisals***, *assessments*.

You don't give an example sentence for usage, but I could imagine the following from your question:

> - Three *appraisals* were left for this item, two of which were positive.
> - Most articles got something in the range of 5 to 10 marks.

---

[1] *Score* has so many meanings that I usually avoid it just to make sure my wording is easier for the reader to parse.

Comment: actually is something like this: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10236/using-color-range-to-make-votes-and-replies-stand-out-without-confusing-the-user (see the vote part)